# What is the Xcode shortcut for the Document Outline Filter on the storyboard view?

Tags: xcode

Is there a shortcut to the `Document Outline` Filter search bar? My goal is to access this quickly to filter constraints by name.

Is there an existing shortcut or how I can create one? I am looking for something similar to 'Filter in Navigator' shortcut for files, which is `ctrl` +`command`+`v`

[image: Xcode Filter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command for that, so there is no shortcut for it.

Comment: If this is important to you, file an enhancement request with Apple. It's a perfectly reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Makes sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the accept; sorry this is not a thing, but I totally agree that it should be.

Comment: Going to take your advice to file an enhancement with Apple. Thanks for the suggestion.